# Issues with autoloading [EDIT]

Tags: php, session, autoloader

I'm having substantial issues with auto-loading currently. I'm currently using multiple directories which segment my application which I know could be structured more efficiently, however for now I'm just trying to get the auto-loader to work.

My directory structure is as follows:

**HTML**

- **classes**

  - config.php
  - db.php
  - register.php
  - reset.php
  - session.php
  - SM_handler.php
  - smtp_handler.php
  - validate.php
- **app**

  - fb_link.php
  - **src**

    - **Facebook Library**
- **phpmailer library**
- **core**

  - init.php (where my autoloader is)
- index.php

Ive tried different autloaders including psr-0, however i don't seem to be able to implement it correctly. For example i'm using:

```
spl_autoload_register( function ($className) {
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName;
});
```

In my index.php file, i'm including the autloader:

```
require_once('/var/www/html/core/init.php');
```

and i've added the namespace to the session class

```
namespace classes;
```

I then call the session class

```
if(!classes\session::exist('ip')){
```

However I keep receiving errors similar to this:

**require(session.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/core/init.php on line 34**

Is my directory structure wrong? Or am I not using psr-0 correctly? I'm stuck to what I can do. Thanks.

EDIT:
I can now instantiate files within the same directory, E.G /classes/, however when i call a class in a different directory, instead of looking the correct folder **/var/www/html/app/fb_link.php**, it looks in **/var/www/html/classes/app/fb_link.php** which then of course throws an error as no file exists. Is this solvable?

Comment: Do you have the html directory in your include path? What get_include_path() is returning?

Comment: the html directory is the directory the site points to so i didn't think that would be required? As for namespaces, i didn't think you needed to include the root?

Comment: I use the `AURA` autoloader currently. It handles both PSR-0 and PSR-4 directories. I have an `application` bootstrap that uses it. I hand coded the paths that the  autoloader uses so I understand it. I have also used the `symfony` autoloader. Both wwork fine. [auraphp/Aura.Autoload
](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Autoload)

Comment: I'll have a look into this, thanks @RyanVincent

Comment: [full, working aura autoloader script - pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RCnQAuwH). It works on windows and linux - don't change the path separator. The application part of the autoloader - this makes it easier to see how to add your directory structure? [namespace prefixes so the autoloader can find our stuff](http://pastebin.com/hUP3F2hi)

Answer (score 0):

Your autoloader function returns "classes/session.php" for "classes\session". Which means "/var/www/html/" has to be in your include path. Try adding:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/var/www/html/',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Or change your autoloader function to include the full file path:

```
require '/var/www/html/' . $fileName;
```

And let me know if this helps.

Comment: the path name does make a difference and has connected files together are in the same directory, however when i look for classes in a different directory, it looks in classes/app instead of just app.

/var/www/html/classes/app/FBlink.php where the actual dir is in

/var/www/html/app/FBlink.php.

Comment: Did you put FBlink also in classes namespace? That would explain this error. Also, I see that FBlink class name doesn't follow the file name fb_link.php. You can't really benefit from autoloader if your class names don't follow the directory structure somehow (with namespaces or prefixes). I would recommend introducing a class map array(className => file) and use it in your autoloader and slowly refactor all your classes to use namespaces.

Comment: the FBlink was in namespace app; I can get it all to work i think but frustratingly i'll need to go through all of the facebook files and give them namspaces likewise with all of the phpmailer files.

Comment: You can install PHPMailer with composer. Composer provides autoload for all libraries installed with it. I don't know which Facebook library you are using but it also might available in compser.